# Java – how to pass records as a single argument?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, record

I'm doing an assignment where I'm writing a program to simulate the Winter Olympics.

My program includes a record with field variables for storing name of country (String), bronzes won, silvers won, and golds won (all int). There will be a method to retrieve info from the record and print medal total for each country.

The assignment guide says that I need to pass the record as a single argument to the method that works out the total. But how is a record passed as a single argument?

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more code in order for us to assist, otherwise it is just guessing on our part.

Comment: How do you store the records?

Comment: If you define your record as `class Record { ... }`, then you could define your method to work out the total as `calculateTotal(Record record)`. That's how you pass a record as a single argument in Java.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a homework solving service

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a class called Record. This class will have members country, bronzes won, silvers and golds.

Or, you can create an object of Map, and the object will contain country, bronzes, silvers and golds all as string. In the method that works out the total, you will need to convert strings to integers for bronzes etc.